# Trying to find multiple things in a text document, and present them back

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to learn python and I'm currently stuck - I'm trying to look for more than one thing in a text document. It'll present back to me the first thing that I'm looking for ('@outlook.com' lines) however, it seemingly doesn't bother to show the second thing I'm looking for (date of birth (DOB)).

I'm not sure if I'm missing some sort of code to enable it to look for something again? I've tried writing it multiple ways but, I've run out of ideas.

I'm not sure if I need to write multiple loops for each time I want to find something?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

```
lcount = 0
for line in fhand:
    lcount = lcount + 1
    line = line.strip()
    if not "@outlook.com" in line:
        continue
    print(line)
## This second set of code doesn't want to run, I know it's looking for the right thing but, it's seemingly not working
    if line.startswith("DOB: "):
        print(line)
##
print("There is", lcount, "lines")
```

Comment: Your code *explicitly* says to go on to the next line if the current one doesn't have `@outlook.com` in it, which means (unless that line *also* contains `@outlook.com`) it will never even check to see if any line starts with `DOB`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I used the 'elif' condition, and that seemed to get me around my issue. Thank you for the help